# Calling apex class from execute anonymous

Tags: execute-anonymous

I have the following class:

```
public class ABC{
    public ABC(Apexpages.standardcontroller s){
        string param1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('v1');
        //blah blah blah
    }
    public void method1(){
    }
}
```

I need to call method1 but at the same time pass parameters.
I tried as we do in test classes:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('v1','somevalue');
ABC cont = new ABC();
```

But this seems to not be working

Comment: ABC cont = new ABC(); cont.method1() ; this works  else move the param1  as class variable

Comment: But how are we setting the value of param1. Anyways can't move it anywhere

Comment: Set param1 to be an instance variable of the ABC class. In the constructor you can populate it with the GET parameter, but in anonymous code you can just set it to a value.

Comment: Hmm so that would mean I have to make param1 a static variable and set  the value from execute anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference `ApexPages.currentPage()` in a non-VF context (i.e. execute anonymous).

You should either test using a browser or use a test method

```
PageReference pg = Test.setCurrentpage(somePage);
pg.getParameters().put('v1','someval');
ABC cont = new ABC(new Apexpages.standardcontroller(someSobject));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class should be modified as shown below:

```
public class ABC{
    public string param1;
    public ABC(Apexpages.standardcontroller s){
        if(param1 != null){
            param1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('v1');
        }
        //blah blah blah
    }
    public void method1(){

    }
}
```

And then create instance of the class --> set value of param1 --> then call method1.

Note: Looking at the constructor this class seems to be an extension to standard controller. so while creating instance of the class pass standard controller to the constructor.

Comment: should not param1 be static. To first set the value and then call constructor.